# Bq Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu edition How to delete cookies and cache in browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, phone, bq, aquaris

How can I delete cookies and the cache content after each session on Bq Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu edition phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Ubuntu Touch OTA-4 update released, the browser now has a privacy mode and some privacy options (clear cache and clear Browsing history) which are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

A setting like that still doesn't exist.

Currently the only way to do it is from the terminal by deleting the content of

**/home/phablet/.local/share/webbrowser-app**

Keep in mind that the bookmarks are also stored in that folder and if you want to keep them you shouldn't delete everything inside.